# Hidden elements of HTML using an array.

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'd like to set the display of 11 elements of a page to none. Instead of doing each one I'd like to set it up in a loop using an array. This is the code I'm using but for some reason the elements won't change their state to none. 
Hoping someone can see my problem.

```
  document.getElementById("b2floor1").addEventListener("click",function loadFloor(){

     var hiddenElements =  [                
                "B3F1",
                "B3F2",
                "B3Title",
                "B5F1",
                "B5F2",
                "B5F3",
                "B5F4",
                "B5F5",
                "B5Title",
                "B2F1",
                "B2Title"                        
     ];




    document.getElementById('viewerDiv').style.visibility = 'visible';
    document.getElementById('hideMap').style.visibility = 'visible';

    for(var i = 0; i < hiddenElements.length; i++){

        document.getElementByID(hiddenElements[i]).style.display = 'none';
    }
```

Comment: you misspelled `getElementByID` = `getElementById`

Comment: Ahhh!! Thank you!! I've done that so many times Not sure how I missed it this time.

Comment: you can delete the question as it's a typo

Comment: Just curious if you even tried to debug this problem yourself. Typing `document.getElementByID('foo')` in the console throws a very descriptive and meaningful error. Did you just type code, pull it up in your browser, see it not working, and then come here to have someone else figure it out for you? I guarantee your browser is trying to tell you that `document.getElementByID` is not a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `getElementByID` to `getElementById`

```
for(var i = 0; i < hiddenElements.length; i++){
    document.getElementById(hiddenElements[i]).style.display = 'none';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your following loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < hiddenElements.length; i++){

    document.getElementByID(hiddenElements[i]).style.display = 'none';
 }
```

If you see above, you are using `getElementByID` which actually should be `getElementById`. The last `d` should be small. So your final code becomes:

```
for(var i = 0; i < hiddenElements.length; i++){

    document.getElementById(hiddenElements[i]).style.display = 'none';
}
```

Its just a typo. Hope it helps :)